# Spliting database according to user's ID

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a database of 5m rows and it grows and it's getting harder and harder to do operations with it.

Is it a good idea to split the table in 10 tables (v0_table, v1_table... v9_table), where the number(v*) is the first number of the user's id?

The user's id in my case are not auto-increment so it would sort the data evenly across those 10 tables.

The problem is I have never done similar things....

Can anyone spot any disadvantages?

EDIT:

I would appreciate any help with tuning the structure or the query.
So the slowest query is the following one:

```
SELECT logos.user, 
       logos.date, 
       logos.level, 
       logos.title, 
       Count(guesses.id), 
       Sum(guesses.points) 
FROM   logos 
       LEFT JOIN guesses 
              ON guesses.user = '".$user['uid']."' 
                 AND guesses.done = '1' 
                 AND guesses.logo = logos.id 
WHERE  open = '1' 
GROUP  BY level
```

Where guesses table:

```
+--------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field  | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| logo   | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| user   | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| date   | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| points | int(4)     | YES  | MUL | 100               |                |
| done   | tinyint(1) | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |
+--------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

LOGOS table:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| img   | varchar(222) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| level | int(3)       | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| date  | timestamp    | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| user  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| open  | tinyint(1)   | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------+----------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys  | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------+------+----------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | logos   | ref  | open           | open | 1       | const |  521 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | guesses | ref  | done,user,logo | user | 4       | const |   87 |                                              |
+----+-------------+---------+------+----------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Seems like that would make the queries terribly confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't that you have too much data, it's that this data is not properly indexed. Try adding an index:

```
CREATE INDEX open_level ON logos(open, level)
```

This should eliminate *Using temporary; Using filesort* on logos.

Basically, you need an index on this table for this query to cover two things: *open* - for `WHERE  open = '1'` and *level* - for `GROUP  BY level` in this order, as MySQL will first filter by *open*, then will group the results by *level* (implicitly sorting by it in process).

Comment: Could you please explain what does it do and why it contains only 'open' and 'level'?

Comment: To be honest, this index helped. Minimized CPU load by 20%. Thank you :) Although OP was different, but you helped with the final request of optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet:  No.  This is never a good idea.  Is your table properly indexed?  Is MySQL properly tuned?  Are your queries efficient?  Are you using any caching?

Comment: Using memcache where I can, have increased mysql cache as well, tables indexed (dunno if properly). The issue is that there are 500 users online and that table is updated really often...
Why is it not good idea?

Comment: Splitting tables a different way might make sense, but not the way you suggested in the OP.  Many databases put the "frequently updated" fields in a table separate from the "hardly-ever-updated"

Comment: That's done. And I am just seeking for extra improvement. Even now it takes 0.3s to get 30 entries (from 5.2m) when only I am online. But when 500users are online it goes wild.

Comment: Sounds to me like the tables are not indexed properly.  Have you setup and checked the mysql slow query log?  Set that up, then do an "explain" on those statements to see if they are using indexes or not, then adjust accordingly.  Other than that without seeing the specific table structure it would be very difficult to help.  The list of reasons why not to do this is quite long in my opinion, but basically it comes down to maintenance and data integrity.

Comment: I have added some more details on the structure of the table. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please do an "explain" on that query and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sharding your table, you may want to examine other tables in your database to see if they can be split off into other dbs. For example tables, that are never joined to are great candidates for this type of vertical partitioning.

This allows you to optimize hardware for smaller sets of data.

Comment: The issue here is that I have 3 tables where 2 of them are frequently used. So that third is separate and often memcached. Can you tell me why is splitting a bad idea.

Comment: In theory, splitting is not a bad idea. You can parallelize queries, have smaller indexes, etc. In practice, MySQL isn't really great for it. In my experience it's been easier to split tables off and work to tune each set of tables independently.

Comment: MySQL does support a partitioning feature, but I'm not sure how well it works in practice. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html